# Could you please explain me the first term of second equation and third equation in the following model?

Tags: education, mathematical-modeling, applications, biology

I have attached the image of the model. Could you please explain me the first term of second equation  and third equation in the following model. (I didn't get the meaning of terms in bracket.)

Comment: Could you say which text do you use ?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you

Comment: I mean : from which book/document/lecture notes is this an excerpt ?

Comment: Do you mean the expression $p_i/(p_i+\phi)$? It describes *saturation*; the effect increases linearly with $p_i$ when $p_i$ is small, but that doesn't go on forever, instead it tends to a constant when $p_i \to \infty$. Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics

Comment: @HansLundmark thanks! and could you pls explain meaning of first term in third equation?

Comment: @JeanMarie from paper by frank : A model for the sequential dominance
of antigenic variants in African trypanosome infections

Comment: It's like a logistic term with carrying capacity $\delta$, just with $m_i^2$ in front instead of $m_i$, so that it has a smaller effect when $m_i \approx 0$.

Comment: @HansLundmark thank you :)

Comment: I haven't be able to upload the document you mention. I have been interested by [this one](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2014.0288), which presents the context, without entering into the modelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a density dependence interaction term between components $a_i$ and $m_i$  which represent parasites and antibodies respectively, with intrinsic growth rate $\rho$ and half saturation constant $\phi$.

Most simpler models have an interaction term that looks something like $\rho a_i m_i$ but there is an underlying physical assumption with this term, called mass action: namely that things are well mixed.  In many cases such as an epidemiological model this is not a particularly good assumption, and while many models make such an assumption anyway, many also do not.

In ecological contexts things of the form $$f(p_i) = \frac{p_i}{p_i + \phi} $$ are called Hollings type II interactions, and if the $p_i$ terms were squared it would be Hollings type III:
$$g(p_i) =\frac{p_i^2}{p_i^2+\phi^2}. $$

With both of these types of interactions they are density dependent in the sense that $$\lim_{p_i\rightarrow\infty} f(p_i) = \lim_{p_i\rightarrow\infty} g(p_i) = 1.$$
Meaning that no matter how abundant the parasite
$$\rho a_i m_i > \rho a_i m_i\frac{p_i}{p_i + \phi} $$
(similar result for $g(p_i)$)

Thus as mentioned above in comments such interaction terms decrease the recrutment rate of component $a_i$.

Below I have included plots of a function of the form of $f(p_i)$, and another of $g(p_i)$, while restricting ourselves to the positive quadrant (assumption of biological models):

[image]

where Hollings type II is of form $f(x) = \frac{bx}{a+x}$
and Hollings type III is of form $g(x) = \frac{bx^2}{a^2+x^2}$